# rsDataSetExecutionError after stored procedure update

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

Let me start by describing my Report Project in BIDS 2008:

- one data source that utilises SQL credentials, linked to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database
- A set of shared datasets deriving data from various stored procedures in the database; most with parameters, some without.
- A set of reports that have embedded datasets that derive data from the shared datasets.

Also I have enabled remote errors on the Report Server.

On the Reports Server, this setup has worked fine for the last 3 years until I needed to re-write a stored procedure that provides data to a report that was taking so long to run it always timed out. The revised stored procedure now runs in 35 secs. compared to 18mins before. The procedure's output has not changed; same number of columns with the same data types.

I have noticed the following behaviour when executing the report. It runs without issue in BIDS but once deployed, running the report produces the following error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   The execution failed for shared dataset 'Recon_Rw_1'. (rsDataSetExecutionError)
>   Query execution failed for dataset ''. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>   There is already an object named 'PK_unit_open_status' in the database. Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Confirmed - the revised procedure does contain temp tables with various indexes. I have monitored the temporary tables created (on tempdb) during the procedure's execution and have confirmed that all the tables are dropped once the procedure terminates - in fact I also have included a section at the end of the procedure to drop all temp tables created.

The report contains 2 embedded datasets that filter data from the shared dataset. The dataset referenced in the above error is one of the embedded ones. The error message sometimes changes to refer to the other embedded dataset.

This is where I'm stumped - what causes this behaviour on the report server? Recall that I've not revised either shared or embedded datasets and the datasource remains as before. All other reports execute without issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be concurrency.   Multiple users running the report attempting to create the same constraint.

Comment: An interesting idea - concurrency - however these are local (as opposed to global) temp tables therefore I do not expect this to be an issue. Unless of course there's some unique characteristic of a shared dataset that I'm not familiar with that triggers the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done to sort this out - I've added 'START TRANSACTION' after the procedure declaration and 'COMMIT TRANSACTION' at the end. I'm not sure if this has any performance drawbacks or poses any risks. Any feedback in this regard is welcome.